# Vertica DB throwing Unavailable: initiator locks for query - Locking failure: Timed out X locking

Tags: database, locking, vertica

I am repeatedly getting this error while trying to run client application which runs query on vertica database table.

Can someone help to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder which kind of "queries" you client application sends to Vertica (SELECTs running in READ COMMITTED mode do not require locks).

Anyhow... first step, check who/what is using your locks:

```
select * from locks ;
```

Then check the session_id from sessions.

Now you can:

**Option 1**: just wait

**Option 2** close the session: `select close_session('<session_id>') ;`

**Option 3** increase the lock timeout in configuration parameters

**Option 4** ... depends on what/why is using your locks ...

Answer (score 1):

This is not my answer but it fixed the error:

> See the LockTimeout configuration parameter:
>
> select * from configuration_parameters where parameter_name =
>   'LockTimeout';
>
> Note that it says to change it only under the guidance of support :-)
>   I don't recall if there's a way to say wait forever, but I also
>   wouldn't recommend doing that. Sometimes you really do want it to
>   timeout, especially when you do something silly or just don't expect
>   what's happening to be happening.
>
> --Sharon

url  http://www.vertica-forums.com/viewtopic.php?t=702